# How to run Quickdialog on iPhone 4.3 simulator?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I'm new to using Quickdialog. I imported QuickDialog in my project following the steps on the official site (my project does not use ARC). I'm using xCode 4.2 but getting "_dyld_dyld_fatal_error" when running on iPhone 4.3 simulator. Please see attached screenshot [here](https://quickdialog.googlegroups.com/attach/1a363b21e5231a3d/crash.png?pli=1&view=1&part=4) for more info in the crash.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the developer, and QuickDialog requires iOS5 and an ARC compiler. You would need to change a lot of code if you were to use it without that, and I have no plans of supporting that.